# bitset operations: flip() vs. the bitwise not (~) operator

Tags: c++11, bitwise-operators, bitset

I found the the following example in the C++ Primer book:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
std::bitset<32> bitvec(1U);
bitvec[0].flip(); // flip the value of the bit at position 0
~bitvec[0];       // equivalent operation; flips the bit at position 0
```

The book claimed that the last two lines of codes are **equivalent** and why is that true? I thought that flip() would change the bitvec variable itself while the bitwise not operator (~) would return a new value.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference

Comment: That does appear to be an error in the book. `.flip()` is a mutating operation. `~` is a non-mutating operation.